# Upgrade Kernel 5.19.0-35-generic [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] not detected anymore

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I am on Kubuntu 22.10. After upgrading to 5.19.0.35 (the other day) the system doesn't detect the sound card any more
I can see the soundcard at Device-2:

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series]
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: NVIDIA GP102 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-4: Logitech C920 PRO HD Webcam type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

But with other commands or `alsamixer` they don't detect it anymore

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [DELL U2414H  ]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

From KDE
[No Soundcard Detected from KDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuOk.png)

Alsactl

```
$ alsactl init
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC1220" "HDA:10ec1168,10438724,00100003" "0x1043" "0x8724"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Found hardware: "USB-Audio" "USB Mixer" "USB046d:08e5" "" ""
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Nvidia GPU 82 HDMI/DP" "HDA:10de0082,19da1474,00100100" "0x19da" "0x1474"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

and lspci:

```
02:00.0 Audio device: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Creative Labs SB1570 SB Audigy Fx
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Could you help me? Not sure where/what to look at. I have never changed any pulse or alsa configuration and always accepted as they work because they do with not much investigations on the whys.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does booting an old kernel resolve the issue? From the GRUB menu, select "Advanced Options..." and pick an older kernel to boot (no need to a select a recovery mode option, just an older kernel version than the top one)