# why my sound card is not detected by alsa?

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics, radeon

os : ubuntu 22.04
VGA : Radeon RX 570 Series

I have sound with mother board sound output.
I have no sound with HDMI output.
The HDMI is hooked up with my graphic card which RX 570.

lspci shows that the audio card has been detected.
[lspci image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xodIO.png)

but at the sound settings
[sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Fuj.png)

pactl shows that the bellow device is the only card which my OS can use.
`$ pactl list short sinks`
`0    alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.4.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE`

I don't know why "snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: no codecs initialized"
$ sudo dmesg | grep snd_hda_
[dmesg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yP6o.png)

i wish to have sound at my HDMI! please help me!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1336087 but you might want to use [`module-alsa-sink`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-alsa-sink) or even `module-alsa-card` and `aplay -l` similar to how `module-alsa-source` and `arecord -l` are discussed in the linked post ... Also please copy/paste text from terminal and don't add screenshots of text for readability.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with the kernel.

Try to boot with an older one. My PC is running with 5.19.35. Started with 5.14.xx (just any older kernel that was installed) and the HDMI devices were found.

See also
[Upgrade Kernel 5.19.0-35-generic [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] not detected anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457574) and [HDMI on AMD video card doesn't work with sound on Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457579)